# swift load customer UIView xib autolayout has lots problems

Tags: ios, uiview

I created two customer thought xib and add constraint
as below:

**UIView1**

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
```

class TestSubView: UIView {

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    loadViewFfromNib()
    setupSubviews()
}

func setupSubviews() {
    view = loadViewFfromNib()
    print("self.view.bounds")
    print(self.view.bounds)
    print("self.view.frame")
    print(self.view.frame)
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFfromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(self.dynamicType), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadViewFfromNib()
    setupSubviews()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //this is for Rect drawer
    self.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    print(self.view.bounds)
    print(self)
    print(self.frame)
    print(self.superview?.frame)
}
```

}

**UIView2**

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
```

class Test2SubView: UIView {

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    loadViewFfromNib()
    setupSubviews()
}

func setupSubviews() {
    view = loadViewFfromNib()
    print(self.view.bounds)
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFfromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(self.dynamicType), bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadViewFfromNib()
    setupSubviews()
}
```

}

**IN main.stroyboard**

I add a UIview with constraint to load my customer UIView

[image]

I load it in a function doxiblayoutTest

```
    func doxiblayoutTest(){
    let value="a"
    switch value {
    case "a":
         let v=TestSubView.init()
         v.frame.origin=xibLayoutTest.frame.origin
        xibLayoutTest.addSubview(v)
    case "b":
         let v=Test2SubView.init()
         xibLayoutTest.addSubview(v)
    default:
         let v=TestSubView.init()
         xibLayoutTest.addSubview(v)
    }
    print("xibLayoutTest.bounds")
    print(xibLayoutTest.bounds)
    print(xibLayoutTest.frame.size)
    print(xibLayoutTest.frame.origin)
}
```

**Result**

[image]

but when i rotation screen .it not display correctly. have anyone can help me!!!!

[image]